# Using waypoint to change the color of navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

So im using waypoints and i want my navigation and logo (which are both fixed) to change color when i hit a certain point in my webpage (which is a one page scroll site) i dont know if this is possible but i assume it is, can anyone help me out

```
"$(window).scroll(function () { 
$('#nav').css('color','#de030c'($(this).scrollTop()/10))
});"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely change the color, you would have to check the scrollTop position and change the color when it is above or below the correct number.

To make things simpler for you, use JQuery Waypoints plugin: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/ and change the color when the waypoint callback gets called.

```
$('.thing').waypoint(function(direction) {
      //Change the background color of the nav
});
```

Comment: im not sure but is my code even remotely correct. I tried to peice together what i saw on another question but im not sure whats wrong...Im not very good with Js as you can tell lol

Comment: If you are not very familiar with Javascript I definitely recommend you use the waypoints plugin I mentioned above as well as JQuery. See the waypoints docs here: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started